# How do I get the headers from a HttpResponse with Spring resttemplate and androidannotations in case of an Error?

Tags: android, spring, rest, error-handling, android-annotations

How do I get the headers from a HttpResponse with Spring resttemplate and androidannotations in case of an Error?

I know how to get them in case of no error but I need them in the errorcase because the api I want to use sends a minorstatuscode to clearify the httpstatuscode.

Comment: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API look at ResponseEntity

Comment: This fine pice is null if there is an error.

Comment: yes.. I assume because an exception is thrown when an error occurs so nothing is returned. I can't find anything in the onRestClientExceptionThrown method to get the headers so where else could I search?

Comment: weird. ResponseEntity<EntityType> should give you http headers. hrmmmmmm.

Comment: are you sure this should happen on errors too?.. because it doesn't make sense.. how should that work? There is definitive an exception thrown either to the customerrorhandler or to the restclient.method() caller.. ergo the return value must be null.

Comment: well. not with client errors. but if you make a request the responds with like a 500 then it should be able to get that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56304/discussion-between-fridolin69-and-bhowden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I found a solution.

The RestClient

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "https://proji.at/japi/v1", converters = { MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class }, interceptors = { HttpBasicAuthenticatorInterceptor.class })
public interface ProjiRestClient extends RestClientErrorHandling {
    RestTemplate getRestTemplate();
}
```

The ErrorHandler:

```
@EBean
public class ProjiResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
    private static final String TAG = "ProjiResponseErrorHandler";

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws     IOException {
        int minor = 0;
        try {
            minor = Integer.parseInt(response.getHeaders().    getFirst("minor"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Response statuscode: " + response.getStatusCode() +     " minor: "
                + response.getHeaders().getFirst("minor"));

        throw new HttpMethodException(response.getStatusCode().value(),     minor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws     IOException {

        Log.i(TAG, "Response statuscode: " + response.getStatusCode());
        if (response.getStatusCode().value() >= 400) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The Fragment that uses the RestClient:

```
@RestService
ProjiRestClient restClient;
@Bean
ProjiResponseErrorHandler projiErrorhandler;

@AfterInject
void afterInject() {
    restClient.getRestTemplate().setErrorHandler(projiErrorhandler);
}
```

And off you go calling methods from the restClient.

```
ResponseEntity<User> respone = restClient.getAuth(auth);
```

If anyone knows a better solution, I'd be pleased to hear from it.